# Incluir en informe de vb 2019 resultados de una dataset

Tags: vb.net, subconsultas

Hola como están estoy intentando incluir un resultado en un informe de rdcl de vb .net
El tema es que si solo coloco un control de campo texto me agrega el valor de la primera fila y para que se vean todos los valores tengo que colocar una tabla lo cual por la.prsentacion del informe no queda bien existe alguna forma de que se pueda agregar por campo y me muestre los por ejm 7 resultados ?

Comment: Si existe, Lo recorres con un for y lo agregas uno a uno como agregarias un campo simple

Comment: Grax pensé que no se podía